# ESTA: one passport eligible, other not

Tags: visas, esta

I have an European passport *(the country where I live in at the moment)* and also a non-EU passport that is not eligible for ESTA (VWP) (Not one of: Iran, Iraq, Libya, Somalia, Sudan, Syria or Yemen).

The new ESTA form confuses me right now. It asks me these questions:

> Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by any other country?

Well, yes, right? I'd say "yes" because I have the non-EU passport, right?

Okay well, let's pretend I said yes....

How is the next question different from that one above?

> OTHER CITIZENSHIP/NATIONALITY
>
> Are you now, a citizen or national of any other country?*

It looks like I should say "yes" on both of them, correct?

Would this bring me in trouble because I have a non eligible passport as well? I have been to the USA a couple of times, but never seen these questions before.

Comment: Whether you are a national or citizen of a country is determined by that country's law. Yet just because you are considered a national by the country's law doesn't mean you necessarily ever applied for its passport.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two are different in that the first means:
Have you *ever* been issued another citizenship document? (i.e. you might not be a citizen of that country anymore)
The second question asks about your current documents.

In general, having another citizenship (and passport) is not a problem when you enter the US under the visa waiver program as long as you show the ESTA-approved passport when boarding your flight and entering the US.

Important addition from the US customs and border protection web site:

> Nationals of VWP countries who have traveled to or been present in Iran, Iraq, Sudan, Syria, Libya, Somalia and Yemen on or after March 1, 2011 (with limited exceptions for travel for diplomatic or military purposes in the service of a VWP country).

Comment: Thanks. What if the passport that is issued, is expired yet I am still a citizen. Would that be a problem?

Comment: No, since you're not travelling with that passport. Basically, normally all they will care about is the passport you show them and the corresponding ESTA approval.